# a oneliner for computing average of a field sorted by a key?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk

I have a list of the following:

```
string1 string2 number
```

and I want to compute the average of the numbers for each identical pair of `string1 string2`.

Is there a oneliner to do it? It would be very easy to do if I didn't need to compute the average for each string separately. Also, it is quite easy to write a perl script that does that, but I am curious if there is a oneliner.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/q/136821/93604

Comment: When you say "each identical pair", do you mean "each pair", or when string1 equals string2.

Comment: @TLP, I mean whenever the two strings in one line equal two other strings in another line.

Comment: so, is `string1 string2` same pair as `string2 string1`?

Answer (score 4):

Although you did not show any of your attempts, it is `awk` and could not help trying it. This is one way:

```
awk '$0{a[$1" "$2]+=$3; b[$1" "$2]+=1} END{for (i in b) print i, a[i]/b[i]}' file
```

- `{a[$1" "$2]+=$3; b[$1" "$2]+=1}` stores in the array `a[]` the sum of the values, while `b[]` counts how many times the pair `$1 $2` has appeared.
- `END{for (i in b) print i, a[i]/b[i]}` prints the result after reading the file.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello bye 3
yeah bye 8
hello bye 3
hello bye 9
yeah bye 6
yeah bye 8
$ awk '$0{a[$1" "$2]+=$3; b[$1" "$2]+=1} END{for (i in b) print i, a[i]/b[i]}' a
hello bye 5
yeah bye 7.33333
```

Answer (score 2):

For each pair `$k` there is sum `$h{$k}{s}` and pair count `$h{$k}{c}` which are divided in order to get average,

```
perl -lane'
  $k = join " ", @F[0,1];
  $_->{s} += $F[2], $_->{c}++ for $h{$k};
  END {
    printf("pair (%s), average: %s\n", $_, $h{$k}{s}/$h{$k}{c})
      for sort keys %h;
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of queries are most easily and flexibly done in SQL. You can use [SQLet](http://www.sqlet.com/) and SQLite for that purpose:

```
sqlet.py -d' ' -A file1.txt 'select a1, a2, avg(a3) from A group by a1, a2' | sqlite3
```